# How to run Flask (flask_discord) and discord.py in the same file

Tags: python, flask

```py
def run():
    bot.loop.create_task(app.run_task(host="127.0.0.1",port=5000))
    bot.run('TOKEN')
```

When I try to run this with Flask, I get an error with the `run_task` part. It worked with Quart. I tried to start the bot only and use the `on_ready` event but it also didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Flask does not have a `run_task` method on the app (only Quart does). Flask can also not be run as a asyncio task. Why not use Quart in this case?

Comment: I tried to use quart and I had a lot of problems I remember, I tried Flask and it worked just fine

If there is no way to run both I guess I'll come back to Quart, but most of the code is ready already and I used Flask